# Number of ways to surround the origin with a chain on the discrete grid

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have a 2-D square lattice and I am interested in finding the number of chains (series of squares) that I can surround the origin with. the length of the chain is from 4 to lets say to 10 squares.
I have found this formula which upper bounds the number of chains $2*(z-2)*3^{z-2}$ where $z$ is the number of squares, the problem is that formula gives loose upper bounds. For example for $z=4$ it gives $2*2*9=36$ ways while practically there is only 1 way.
Any help, guidance will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Better with an example.

Comment: @Fei Gao, Assume u have some point (say the origin) in a 2-D square lattice and you want to surround it with a chain of length N.a chain is a closed path of squares, say N is 10, so how many ways are there to surround the origin with 10 squares (what is the formula for that)?

Comment: What is the answer for $z=6?$  Your squares must be a $2\times 3$ block, but (for the horizontal position) the origin can be on the left or the right.  So is the answer $1,2,$ or $4$?  I can answer odd $z$

Comment: @Ross Millikan, Okay I get your point, let us assume that the origin in a single box and we are talking about surrounding that whole box. So to start with we need at least 8 boxes to surround it.

Comment: You still need to say you want the number of shapes or the origin location matters within a shape.  Now for $z=10$ we get a $3 \times 4$ rectangle with a $1 \times 2$ hole.  Is that $1,2,$ or $4$ solutions, counting orientation and which of the squares in the hole is the origin?  With higher numbers the question of counting reflections as different will come up.  All are reasonable ways to count, but the answer will be different.  I don't know if one will be easier than another.  Often it is a useful approach to calculate the first few terms and try OEIS.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, That is a 1-solution. The orientation doesn't matter because all of them are identical. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.  It is almost done specifying what we are counting.  In the figure below, the first shape is the only path with length $8$.  The next three have length $10$.  Are the last two allowed, with a square that touches three others?  Are the last two the same, as they are reflections of each other.  As we count rotations the same, I suggest we count reflections the same as well.  In that case there are two paths of length $10$.  I have found $10$ length $12$ paths, shown in the last two lines.  I suspect it is not complete.  I believe a hand (or computer) count of length $14$ would suffice to see if the sequence is in OEIS, but this is not enough-it yields $182$ pages.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this clearly clarifies what the problem is. By the way what is the OEIS?

Comment: It is The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences® (OEIS®), found at oeis.org  You can search it for any string of numbers you want.  If you search this site for OEIS, you will find many links.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that, I am just curious about the squares that are shown in the figure, did you hand-drawn them one-by-one or u generated them some way else?

Comment: I drew one in PowerPoint, then used the selection arrow, copy/paste and drag to make more.  Saved to jpg and done.

Comment: Thx alot. I will keep updating the post If I find some ways to do it. As for now, I am thinking of developing a Dynamic Programming algorithm to count the ways. The current problem is some-how similar to the RNA problem (section 6.5 in Algorithms Design by Kleinberg)